visual studio 2017 version 15.0
I have C++ and Qt production code with .exe files. While I can build and generate binaries, the .exe files don't work as expected (likely due to thread handling issues).
I want to set up a development environment to proceed with new feature changes without altering the existing code and binary behavior.
Below are screenshots comparing the production binaries with the ones I built. The compiler differences are evident.
I need the exact Visual Studio 2017 version to match the production environment, but I can't find the correct download link.
Any suggestions?
Compiler: EP:Microsoft Visual C/C++(2013-2017)[EXE32]
Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++(2017 v.15.0)[-]
Linker: Microsoft Linker(14.10, Visual Studio 2017 15.0*)[Console32,console]


The only official downlooad link I could find is at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/.

@OldBoy  yess, and even after signing in it have redistribution package link. not the  visualstudio2017

This is not really programming problem that we can resolve for you. This is strictly a Microsoft issue, and you would be better using their help forum.

You could download VS2017 via this link:
https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_community.exe
.However if you are requesting the exact same version,the
Developer Community (visualstudio.com)
would be the best place for you to request offical support.
